# Como funciona a integração do Google Maps na versão web?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mime-type

Olá!
Minha pergunta pode parecer meio vaga, mas não sabia como sintetizar em poucas palavras a minha dúvida.
O que eu quero saber é: como o Google Maps valida API_KEY e devolve o mapa, na integração web?
Basicamente, a parte de backend e frontend eu consigo me virar, mas como funciona essa funcionalidade do Google Maps que valida a API_KEY, chama um callback e renderiza na tela?

Não sei se deu pra entender a pergunta, mas não é nada de JS ou backend. Basicamente, quais recursos/tecnologias eu precisaria conhecer/estudar pra conseguir criar algo parecido (pensando em tecnologia, não em produto)? Tem algo a ver com mime-type ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Você quer criar um serviço onde os usuários precisariam de uma API_KEY para que pudessem usar @Claudio Neto ?

Comment: O que eu preciso é, basicamente, permitir o usuário integrar dessa maneira:

`<div id="test"></div>
<script src="MinhaUrlDoServiço?key=API_KEY"></script>
<script>
  var testeApp = ObjectApp.RenderApplication($('#test'));
</script>`

Pela url do meu JS, eu validaria a API_KEY e retornaria o conteúdo do JS, pra que a minha aplicação pudesse ser renderizada.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste e consegui resolver.
Basicamente, foi isso que eu fiz:

C#

```
public HttpResponseMessage Index(string key)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StringContent("function Console() { console.log('Funcionou - " + key + "'); }");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/javascript");
    return response;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="http://localhost:41852/api/Scripts?key=123456"></script>
<script>
    Console();
</script>
```

O Javascript retornado pelo C# é integrado no meu site e a function Console passa a existir, sem dar erro algum no console dizendo que a function Console não foi definida.